# Caching Big Amount Of Data and Data Location is Faraway

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

I am working on a asp.net Mvc Project and We are caching every content of the page

just like the below

```
[Cache( EntityName = CacheEntityNames.PromotionKey, SecondsInCache = CacheDuration.OneDay )]
```

My problem is I can not remove caching, and the caching data is around 400 MB, and database is 2000km away from here and also I have only 10mb internet speed.

So Everytime I change something in backend and compile it, I have at least 5 minute waiting time for caching data.

I am using IIS 7.5 and I never had this problem before. I did some research on it.

After the research, what I can do is

1. I can create localDb,[but I am not allowed to it]
2. I can remove caching codes[I can not, because, I am a developer and I can't have a huge difference on my local project with the tfs project. I can merge this removed lines to the development project easily by forgetting, :D it is possible when you focus on your real task]

Any help or Idea will be appreciated if it can be done at IIS side